# Compare arrays in PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have following arrays in Powershell that I want to compare:

```
Array1: 
Srvname Loginname sid passwordhash 
Srv1     L1        0xdbc  0xfsfhdfh
Srv2     L2        0xdbe  0xfsfhdfe
Srv3     L3        0xdbc  0xfsfhdfd
 
Array2: 
Srvname Loginname sid passwordhash
Srv1     L1        0xdbd  0xfsfhdfh 
Srv2     L2        0xdbe  0xfsfhdfh
Srv3     L3        0xdba  0xfsfhdfb
```

It should give output only when there is either sid,password or both mismatch of the same loginname. For example in above case it should give output as below:

```
Srvname Loginname Srvname2 Loginname2 Mismatch
Srv1      L1       Srv1     L1         sid
Srv2      L2       Srv2     L2         password
Srv3      L3       Srv3     L3         sid and password
```

If someone can assist with the code that would be greatly appreciated.

Tried below but it didn't work:

```
$output += $T2 | ForEach-Object {
    $r = $_
    $T1 | Where-Object { $_.LoginName -eq $r.LoginName -and ($_.SId -ne $r.SId -or $_.PasswordHash -ne $r.PasswordHash) } |
        Select-Object @{Name = 'SrvName'; Expression = { $_.srvname }}, $_.LoginName, @{Name = 'SrvName2'; Expression = { $r.srvname } }, @{Name = 'LogiName2'; Expression = { $r.LoginName }}, @{Name = 'Mismatch'; Expression = { 'sid or password' }}
}
```

Comment: did you try anything already? are those powershell objects? also your expected output in the first object, `Srv1      L1       Srv2     L1` there is no correlation between those 2

Comment: I guess you want to join the two arrays on the  `Srvname` and `Loginname` and then find the discrepancies (as different sids): Using this [`Join-Object Module`](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/JoinModule) (see also: [In Powershell, what's the best way to join two tables into one?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45483110/1701026)): `$Array1 | Join $Array2 -On Srvname, Loginname -Name *1, *2 | Where-Object { $_.sid1 -ne $_.sid2 }`

Comment: @SantiagoSquarzon Updated question with what I tried.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming these are arrays of objects, using this as an example:

```
$arr1 = @'
Srvname Loginname sid passwordhash
Srv1     L1        0xdbc  0xfsfhdfh
Srv2     L2        0xdbe  0xfsfhdfe
Srv3     L3        0xdbc  0xfsfhdfd
'@ -replace ' +', ',' | ConvertFrom-Csv


$arr2 = @'
Srvname Loginname sid passwordhash
Srv1     L1        0xdbd  0xfsfhdfh
Srv2     L2        0xdbe  0xfsfhdfh
Srv3     L3        0xdba  0xfsfhdfb
'@ -replace ' +', ',' | ConvertFrom-Csv
```

You can use `Group-Object` grouping by `Loginname` then you can filter where their `sid` on both sides is not equal OR their `passwordhash` is not equal and if the condition is met, then output the differences. **The code below assumes that `Loginname` is unique on each side.**

```bash
$arr1 + $arr2 | Group-Object Loginname | ForEach-Object {
    $sid = $_.Group.sid
    $passwordhash = $_.Group.passwordhash

    $mismatch = @(
        if ($sid[0] -ne $sid[1]) {
            'sid'
        }

        if ($passwordhash[0] -ne $passwordhash[1]) {
            'password'
        }
    ) -join ' and '

    if ($mismatch) {
        [pscustomobject]@{
            SrvnameLEFT  = $_.Group.Srvname[0]
            SrvnameRIGHT = $_.Group.Srvname[1]
            Loginname    = $_.Name
            Mismatch     = $mismatch
        }
    }
}
```

The output you would get from this example:

```
SrvnameLEFT SrvnameRIGHT Loginname Mismatch
----------- ------------ --------- --------
Srv1        Srv1         L1        sid
Srv2        Srv2         L2        password
Srv3        Srv3         L3        sid and password
```